# MiniDLNA: not recognizing additional mount points

Tags: linux, centos6, dlna, mount-point

I have a volume mounted at `/media`.
I have an additional volume mounted at `/media/dvd`.

I have mounted things this way as I understand that **minidlna** can only use a single directory for, say, videos.

Each volume is structured with sub directories. On the main director, `/media` everything works, the folder structure works, and adding new files appear automatically.

I cannot get **minidlna** to recognise the `/media/dvd` directory. I have tried to restart, force-reload, and even deleted the `files.db` file to force a refresh.

I don’t know whether the issue is:

- The fact that I have one mount point inside another
- The permissions need fixing
- The fact that the second volume `/media/dvd` is **HFS+**; the volume mounts well enough and I can read & write from the shell (`touch test`).
- Something else … ?

I am running Centos 6.

Comment: might be a problem with external drives, probably related with the ability to sharing the drive